# move_uploaded_file() does not work

Tags: php

I run my test php project on local computer using XAMPP. I have a form where user can browse image from their computer and upload to my database.

I use `move_uploaded_file()` function to move image to desired folder. The script runs without error but no image was moved to desired folder. It does not echo error message if `move_uploaded_file()` failed. Here is my code:

```
$upload_dir= 'uploads';
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);$i++){
  if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])){
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

        if(!in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
            echo  "Only image ending with .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png is allowed";
        }
        // copy the file to the specified dir 
        else{
            $name[$i] = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_dir.'/'.$name[$i])){
                $image_path_array[$i]=$upload_dir.'/'.$name[$i];
            }
            else{
                /*** an error message ***/
                echo "error with move_uploaded_file";
            }

         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Where is $upload_dir ??

Comment: sorry i did declared $upload_dir, but i forgot to include it in this. Changed it

Comment: Had a problem like that. Solved it with `copy()` and `unset()` ... It's a workaround.

Comment: correct your echo statement.

Comment: that was my mistake, but in my form there is no = in echo.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your echo statements is likely to work that way.  It should be

```
echo "error with move_uploaded_file";
```

No "=" sign.

Also, are you sure your web server has permission to write into the upload directory?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

1) I think you should give full directory path to your **$upload_dir** variable something like this:

```
$upload_dir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads";
```

2)Yes the echo that you have given for display **"error with move_uploaded_file"** need to correct other wise it will give syntax error:

```
//an error message
echo "error with move_uploaded_file";
```

I hope this fix your problem :)

Comment: i dont think there is error with my $upload_dir because when i first submit the form, move_uploaded_file() worked. But when I edit this form to upload more image or replacing old image with new one, somehow it did not move the image to uploads folder?

Comment: yes it may also works but i am not sure for that since it might create some problem at server so it would be good to give full path instead of relative

Answer (score -2):

You should have separate move_uploaded_files() function for image on server and image on client machine.

1. Image from client machine will be uploaded to your server temp folder
2. Image on online server will be fetched as url to that image